# prove that any set $S$ subset of {1,2,,...100} with |S|=26 contains at least one odd number or y is divisible by x, where y different from x

Tags: discrete-mathematics

prove that any set $S \subset\{1,2,,...100\}$ with $|S|=26$ contains at least one odd number or it contains two numbers $x$ different from $y$ for which $x\,|\,y$.

I know I should use pigeonhole principle, but I am having trouble to come up with an idea of what to consider as pigeonholes. I was thinking to consider two cases, one where I have at least one odd number but not necessarily $x\,|\,y$, and the opposite.

Comment: This has nothing to do with probability.  There are no random choices here.

Comment: If it contains an odd number, you're done, so you only need to consider even numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it has no odd number, then every number is even, so divide them all by $2.$ Now you have $26$ numbers between $1$ and $50.$ Can you finish the argument?